# Multiple [ngTemplateOutlet] displays first one only for others also

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to get multiple template refs using `@ContentChild` but first one is displayed.

**modal.component.html**

```
<div class="ac-modal">
 <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="modalHeader"></ng-container>
 <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="modalBody"></ng-container>
 <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="modalFooter"></ng-container>
</div>
```

**modal.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ac-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterContentInit {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) modalHeader: TemplateRef<void>;
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) modalBody: TemplateRef<void>;
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) modalFooter: TemplateRef<void>;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log("HEADER: ", this.modalHeader);
        console.log("body: ", this.modalBody);
        console.log("footer: ", this.modalFooter);
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ac-modal>
    <ac-modal-header *acModalHeader></ac-modal-header>
    <ac-modal-body *acModalBody></ac-modal-body>
    <ac-modal-footer *acModalFooter></ac-modal-footer>
</ac-modal>
```

**modal-footer.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[acModalFooter]'
})
export class ModalFooterDirective {
    constructor(tempalteRef: TemplateRef<void>,
                modalComponent: ModalComponent) { 
          modalComponent.modalFooter = tempalteRef;
    }
}
```

**modal-header.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[acModalHeader]'
})
export class ModalFooterDirective {
    constructor(tempalteRef: TemplateRef<void>,
                modalComponent: ModalComponent) { 
          modalComponent.modalHeader = tempalteRef;
    }
}
```

**modal-body.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[acModalBody]'
})
export class ModalFooterDirective {
    constructor(tempalteRef: TemplateRef<void>,
                modalComponent: ModalComponent) { 
          modalComponent.modalBody = tempalteRef;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
modal-header works!

modal-header works!

modal-header works!
```

Whichever tag I put first in `modal.component.html` inside `<ac-modal>` component gets displayed 3 times. 3 times because I have 3 `<ng-container>` in `modal.component.html` but I am not able to figure out why this is happening because I am passing different templaterefs for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying for `TemplateRef`, so Angular will always give you the first one. You want to target the specific directives you need:

```
@ContentChild(ModalHeaderDirective, {read: TemplateRef}) modalHeader: TemplateRef<void>;
@ContentChild(ModalBodyDirective, {read: TemplateRef}) modalBody: TemplateRef<void>;
@ContentChild(ModalFooterDirective, {read: TemplateRef}) modalFooter: TemplateRef<void>;
```

If you do this, you don't even need to inject `ModalComponent` in the directives anymore, the `@ContentChild` is enough to get the `TemplateRefs`.

Comment: thanks Eudes, that makes sense now. Is it possible to use renderer2 to add classes to Header, Body and Footer from `modal.component.ts` ? Because `ContentChild` will provide TempletRef since I asked for it but `modalHeader.elementRef.nativeElement` is a comment.

Comment: `TemplateRef` is a "black box", you won't be able to modify what's inside of it from the Modal component. The `ac-modal-header` component will have to add a class itself to the host.

Answer (score 0):

Because `ContentChild` only gets first matching selector

change **modal.component.ts** to

```
modalHeader: TemplateRef<void>;
modalBody: TemplateRef<void>;
modalFooter: TemplateRef<void>;

@ContentChildren(TemplateRef) templateRefs;

ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.templateRefs.forEach((template: TemplateRef<void>) => {
    if (template === this.modalHeader) {
     //here you can do stuff for ModalHeaderComponent
    }

});
```

}